# Prettier Extension won't format my code on VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

When I installed Prettier for the first time a month or two ago, it worked fine. However, I ended up disabling it at some point because I didn't want it on a different project. However, upon re-enabling it, I found that it didn't work anymore. For about three weeks now, I haven't been able to get it to work again. I've tried all that I can.

I have Prettier as my default formatter.
[image]

I've turned on "Format On Save" for both User and Workspace, with "Format On Save Mode" set to `file`.
[image]

I tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code, adding `"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"` to settings.json, and uninstalling ESlint but none of that worked. Prettier doesn't even show up at the bottom of the screen :(

Answer (score 0):

try to:

```
npm install --save-dev prettier
```